# Project Euler 1 too slow with triangular numbers

Tags: clojure

I was trying to solve Euler Project problem 1. I have noticed a sequence leading to a quicker solution of every 15th number.

This is the Clojure code

```
  (defn fifteenator [n]
  (* 15 (+ (* (+ 1 n) 3) (* (/ (+ (* n n) n) 2) 7))))
```

for 15 n is 0 for 30 n is 1 and so on.

So I can calculate the nearest number divisible by 15 and do only a few recursive calculations. But still one of the HackerRank test cases times out. Before I start profiling the code I would like to make sure if my reasoning is correct. Is there a quicker way to calculate it, or should I learn to profile Clojure?

Comment: Have you considered using [apply](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply) and [filter](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/filter) instead?

Comment: You can time the evaluation by wrapping the statement in [`time`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/time) which prints the time it took to standard out.

Comment: A few hints: 1. The sequence of multiples of `i` up to but not including `n` is `(range i n i)`. 2. You can use `(reduce + ...)` or `(apply + ...)` to sum a sequence. 3. If you sum the multiples of 3 and those of 5, you will count the multiples of 15 twice. There are faster solutions using the algebra of [arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum)

Comment: The same algorithm in SBCL Common Lisp has ran all the puzzles in less than a second. I guess I need to learn to profile Clojure.

Comment: Well, the code you gave just consists of basic math and is not recursive.  So that function shouldn't take more than a few nanoseconds.  Since you don't give us the rest of your algorithm, it's impossible for us to say whether there is a faster way of doing it or not.

Comment: Could the problem be with reading the test data being too slow?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your approach. Clojure has excellent support for ranges and filters. With these solving Euler 1 is not too difficult:

```
(defn euler1 
  [n] 
  (reduce + 
    (filter #(or (= (rem % 5) 0) (= (rem % 3) 0)) (range n))))
```

Testing if we are getting the right result:

```
user=> (euler1 10)
23
```